# Android InApp Purchase: getPurchases returns empty bundle

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

When using the following code, I get an empty bundle as a result.

`Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(), "inapp", null);`

The bundle is completely empty, it even does not contain empty lists, neither a return code. When I try to purchase an item using the purchase flow proposed by Google, I get an error which says that the item has already been purchased, so effectively there seem to be purchased items.

Querying a list of available items and purchasing managed in app prodocts works fine, only getPurchases() does not work.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks.